# Find android apps by intent

Tags: android, google-play

Im using an intent to invoke an external qr code scanner app, specifically "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN".

We have been using "QR Droid Private", but having some problems lately with this app, and wanted to switch.

Is there a way to search google play (or any private apk mirror) for apps that will respond to this intent?

(There are a million scanner apps on play, and its very tedious to test every one for this manually...)